# How do I publish an angular application using Github pages?

Tags: angular, github

I'm attempting to [publish](https://jackanichp.github.io/angular-app/) an [angular app](https://github.com/jackanichp/angular-app) on github using Github pages.

I would expect the `index.html` to be published; but instead the `dist` folder contains a `README.md` file.

I followed all of the steps [here to publish](https://uxworks.online/how-to-deploy-an-angular-app-on-github-pages/) the page.

How do I publish an angular application using github pages?

Comment: I think, you should accept my answer atleast

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial :

> It is a library which is used to publish any site to any gh-pages
>   branch on GitHub.  The angular-cli-ghpages command is able to push to
>   any branch on any repository.

But you only have `master` branch, so git pages launch your readme.md file as it is not index.html on the root of master and no branch named `gh-pages`.

**I think you have missed/made-mistakes in following the steps from tutorial.**

**Manually** : **[Simple Steps](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages)**

> Copy your all files within build to directly within `gh-branch` and push.
>
> OR Just keep all those build files in `master` and remove rest of the
>   files and push new build every time on `master`.

Then you can select one of this from the above choice and publish

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Step 1. run `ng build --prod --output-path docs` in shell;
Step 2. copy the docs/index.html and paste it in the same folder; rename the copy 404.html;
Step 3. run `npx ngh --dir=docs/`;
Step 4. change the github pages source to master branch/docs folder